# Exercise about refraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, quantum-optics

I'm a highschooler and I'm trying to self-study the part of the program about optics. I'm having troubles understanding how to solve the following exercise (I'm using an italian book, hence the following is a translation):

> A light source is oriented towards the wall of an acquarius, whose thickness is negligible, to illuminate a starfish on the bottom. The distance of the starfish from the wall is $80\mathrm{cm}$, while the light enters the acquarius at an height of $1,4\mathrm m$ from the bottom. Calculate the angle of incidence.

Now let:

$d = 80\mathrm{cm} = 0,80\mathrm m \\ h = 1,4\mathrm m$

And let $l$ be the hypothenuse of the right triangle whose catheti are $d$ and $h$. Hence using Pythagorean theorem $l = \sqrt{(d^2 + h^2)}$. Let $\theta_2$ (this is the refraction angle) be the concave angle between the normal at the point where the light enters the acquarius, and $l$. Since the normal is parallel to $d$ and they are both cut by the transverse $l$, the concave angle between $d$ and $l$ is $\theta_2$ too. The situation looks like this:

[image]

Thus let $\theta_1$ be the incidence angle. Write the refraction coefficients as follows:

$n_2 = n_{H_2 O} = 1,33 \\ n_1 = n_{air} \sim 1,00$

Moreover:

$\sin \theta_2 = \frac{h}{l} = \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2 + d^2}}$

And applying the Snell's law:

$n_1 \sin \theta_1 = n_2 \sin \theta_2 \Longrightarrow \sin \theta_1 = n_{H_2 O} \sin \theta_2 = n_{H_2 O} \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2 + d^2}} \Longrightarrow \theta_1 = \arcsin \left( n_{H_2 O} \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2 + d^2}} \right)$

By substituting the proper values, the number inside the $\arcsin = \sin^{-1}$ function is greather than one ($= 1,15$), which results in a nondefined value for $\theta_1$. I'm pretty sure the Snell's law is applied correctly (I've also tried reading its Wikipedia page) and that the situation described by the problem could have a tangible phyisical meaning. Moreover I'm sure that the exercise I wrote here is the same as the one contained inside the book I'm following. How is it possible that I'm obtaining a nondefined value? Could there be an error in the book? Two more whings:

1. I've randomly tryied to calculate $\frac{h}{n_{H_2 O} \sqrt{h^2 + d^2}} = 41°$ which is precisely the result given by the text
2. I'm aware that the representation of the physical situation is not correct, since $n_2 = n_{H_2 O} > n_2 = n_{air}$ it should, in fact, be $\theta_2 < \theta_1$, but the graphic I've drawn is the same as the one I'm induced to draw by the image under the exercise. By the way, if anyone knows it, the textbook is "Dalla mela di Newton al bosone di Higgs" ("From Netwton's apple to the Higg's boson") by Ugo Amaldi

P.S. Thank you in advance for your eventual answers and excuse my yet poor English: I'm still practising it!

Comment: It's possible to specify a physically unrealizable problem, which in my opinion, the author of your question has done.

Comment: $\rm d\boldsymbol \longleftrightarrow h\:$  so
$$
\sin\theta_1\boldsymbol=n_{water}\dfrac{\rm d}{\sqrt{\rm h^2\boldsymbol+\rm d^2}}\boldsymbol=0.6599 \boldsymbol\implies \theta_1\boldsymbol= 41.29^{\rm o}
$$

Comment: @DavidWhite, it was also my thought.

Comment: @Frobenius, are you suggesting the hypothesis are wrong and that $d$ and $h$ whould be swapped or are you suggesting I was wrong and I should have swapped them. In the latter case, could you please explain me how is it possible?

Comment: I appreciate if you could give me the exact location of your exercise (page of which chapter of which Volume) and I draw a Figure for your question. In any case your question  will be closed and it's not permitted users to give complete or near complete answer.

Comment: The maximum angle of refraction is $(\theta_2)_{\rm max}\boldsymbol = 48.75^{\rm o}$ (take  $\theta_1\boldsymbol = 90.00^{\rm o}$) while in your drawing $\theta_2\boldsymbol = 60.26^{\rm o}$. Connection with your answer about  $\theta_2\boldsymbol = 41^{\rm o}$ let me suppose the swap.

Comment: @Frobenius, the problem is in volume 1+2 (for first and second years), chapter 3, page 133, number 59

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128850/discussion-between-frobenius-and-luke).